# AndroidOpenGL drawing loop and passing drawing information

Tags: android, multithreading, opengl-es, synchronization

I am using GLSurfaceView for my application's core drawing process.

I do my drawing onDrawFrame ( a function that gets called as often as possible, like thread loop ).

However when touch event occurs I use different class that manages all the user input.

Problem rises when the this "input manager" tried to talk to "draw manager".

my input manager tells draw manager a new set of coordinates (distorted shape, modified by the user) that draw manager should draw.

However since input manager passes this new drawing items very frequently I think this unexpected behavior occurs :

The shape that's being rendered flickers (disappears for a sec) or at some point, when "drawing manager" receives and tried to set a new buffer data, it throws out of index error(since I need to move buffer index as I read the buffer; if I try to set a new buffer data while I am reading also as well, it results in an unexpected behavior).

I lack experience to deal with this situation that I am facing. What will be a way to make sure "storing" and"reading" do not occur at the same time?

Comment: Synchronize the getter/setter of that data.

Comment: I wrapped the object being used in synchronized (synchronized(this): java code), but the problem still prevails.

Comment: then have getter give a copy of data, instead of the original.

Comment: it does give a copy to drawing manager, but when drawing manager takes the data, it puts the data into the object that's being currently read( as far as I observed ). However I do not know how to distinguish between the two process since synchronized block does not seem to effect. What I was thinking was having stacked copy somewhere stored and when each time I finish drawing, I could check whether I have any stacks given, if so then update the drawing info? but that did not seem like the best solution.